# USB power delivery and data transfer using type c

Tags: power-supply, power, pcb-design, usb-device, usb-c

I have recently been designing a soldering station that uses Weller active tips and have become interested in using USB power delivery to power the station I have found the [STUSB4500](https://www.st.com/en/interfaces-and-transceivers/stusb4500.html) which looks relatively easy to use and has 3 power profiles. I was wondering whether using this ic I would still be able to plug the port into my pc to program the on board stm32 if I added a 5v profile and when plugged into a wall port I could negotiate for 12v for day to day operation? Thanks.

Comment: Hello Joshua. Your first question is a little fragmented and as such is not getting much attention. Please revise your question by first fully describing your intended device with either a block diagram or clear text. Next describe your problem (USB-PD profiles). Next describe what you've done to try and solve the problem (read datasheets, prototype, etc) then finally ask your question.

Comment: Example: "I'm designing a USB powered soldering station using Weller active tips, and an STM32 micro (doing something). I want to use USB-PD so that the micro is powered with a 5V contract (and can be programmed) when connected to a PC, and want to negotiate a 12V contract from a wall adapter for regular use..."

Comment: Thanks for the advise, i shall re write my question to make it more clear